# How to render this JSON object in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
{
    "code": "00100300",
    "lastupdate": "08/Mar/2022 16:55",
    "name": "080",
    "ordernumber": "4365873",
    "projectdescription": "LVB - Smart Device - CIC 833",
    "referencecode": null,
    "status": "In Use",
    "statuscolor": "GREEN",
    "workcenters": [
        {
            "workcenterCode": "00200500",
            "workcenterColor": "GREEN",
            "workcenterName": "Manual Pack_080 (Dosepak ®)",
            "workcenterStatus": "In Use",
            "job": {
                "jobUid": 135355,
                "jobDescription": "4: [CIC833PROD2]1 X Dosepak ® Inner (Wallet) -> Dosepak ® (PBOEL = Not Classi...",
                "jobProgress": "5/30 ( 17% )",
                "jobStatus": "In Progress",
                "jobStatuscolor": "GREEN"
            }
        }
    ],
    "errorDescription": null
}
```

I am getting this JSON object from an API call.....but unable to render this in react js.
To be clear I would like it rendered with a structure like this:
|code,lastupdate,name,ordernumber...|
____|workcenters[0] (workcenterCode, workcenterColor...|
________|job (jobUid, jobDescription, jobProgress, jobStatus, jobStatuscolor)|
...
I want to display the whole object on the website ...How should I access all of its attributes ?

Comment: Well it depends how you want it displayed... if you are parsing this json into a object then you can access the elements as you would a normal object. If so then render it however you like (using react inline variables most likely). Otherwise if you just want to display this JSON as you have here. you can litterally inject this JSON object into it using `<div>{JSON.stringify(myApiResponse)}</div>`. Can you please clarify your question.

Comment: Actually according to the JSON, 3 objects are there .....First object after that the 2nd workcenters that has ManyToOne relation with the first object and then the 3rd object Jobs that has ManyToOne relation with the workcenters. So I want to display the first object and inside it the workcenters related to it and inside the workcenters I want to display the jobs related to it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to stringify the json using JSON object in javascript and then put it to idealy pre tag in html like this

```
const stringObj = JSON.stringify(yourObject);

<pre>{stringObj}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to store this JSON data in some variable `const jsonData = JSON.stringify(yourJSONdata)` then you can display it by accessing properties and mapping over it on it. have a look at this code

```
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(yourJSONdata)

return(

  // "code": "00100300",
  <p> {jsonData.code} </p> // so on

  // in case you have array do, map over it
  {jsonData && jsonData.map ( (data , idx) => 
       // render it ...
       
       //"workcenters": [ JSON DATA .. ]
       data.workcenters.map ( (ele , idx) =>{
         // render ..

         // "job" : {...}
         const jobData = ele.job
         // render jobData ..
       )}
  )}
);
```

Comment: Actually according to the JSON, 3 objects are there .....First object and after that the 2nd object which is workcenters that has ManyToOne relation with the first object and then the 3rd object Jobs that has ManyToOne relation with the workcenters. So I want to display the first object and inside it the workcenters related to it and inside the workcenters I want to display the jobs related to it.

Comment: the answer has been updated check this out

Answer (score 1):

```
function RenderApiInput({apiResponseObj}){
    const {code, lastupdate, name, ordernumber, projectdescription,
        referencecode, status, statuscolor, workcenters,
        errorDescription} = apiResponseObj; //pulling out attributes here
    return (
        <div className="api-response">
            <p>{code}</p>
            <p>{lastupdate}</p>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{ordernumber}</p>
            <p>{projectdescription}</p>
            <p>{referencecode}</p>
            <p>{status}</p>
            <p>{status}</p>
            {workcenters.map(v=>(
                <div className="work-center">
                    <p>{v["workcenterCode"]}</p>
                    <p>{v["workcenterColor"]}</p>
                    //... render the workcenter attributes just like this one for basic example
                    <div>
                        <p>{v["job"]["jobUid"]}</p>
                        <p>{v["job"]["jobDescription"]}</p>
                        //... render the jobs accordingly if you want it nested as you mentioned in the comment.
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
            <p></p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RenderApiInput;
```

in Whatever react component you want to render this apiReponse you can use this like so:

```
<RenderApiInput apiResponseObj={responseObj} />
```

Because this is basic javascript (accessing a javascript object elements and inner elements I recommend you read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp), [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and [this](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/rendering-variables-in-react). However if you are able to make api requests, I would assume you already know the first link I shared.

Comment: May be consider this: `const {workcenter, ...rest} = apiResponseObj;`. Then within the JSX: `<div className="api-response"><div>{Object.values(rest).map(el => (<p>{el}</p>))}</div><div>{workcenter.map(....)}</div></div>`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')...getting this error

Comment: Just to confirm: `workcenter.map` on the above answer has a typo. It needs to be `workcenters.map`. Did you manage to change the variable name?

Comment: Ah yes, fixed that typo, that is why @AghaZafeer is getting undefined error on the 'map'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render it first you will have to stringify your data -> JSON.stringify(apiResponse), but if you are looking just to display it as it is you could use [react-json-pretty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-pretty) dependency.